# X and Y are independent, binomial random variables with different probabilities. How would I find the conditional probability of their sum?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

Let X have binomial distribution with parameters $n = 4$ and $p = 0.75$,
and Y have have binomial distribution with parameters $n = 5$ and $p = 0.5$.
Suppose $X, Y$ are independent. Let $Z = X + Y$

For $2 ≤ k ≤ 7$, how would I obtain $P(X = 2 | Z = k)$. How would I proceed with this?

I am aware that this is

$$\frac{P(X=2, Z=k)}{P(Z=k)}$$
$$\frac{P(X=2)P(Y=k-2)}{P(X+Y=k)}$$

If this is right, how would I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally assume that $X\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y\sim\mathsf{Bin}(m,q)$ are independent, and $Z=X+Y$. For $0\leqslant i\leqslant k\leqslant n+m$ we would have by definition of conditional probability
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=i\mid Z=j) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=i,Z=k)}{\mathbb P(Z=k)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(X=i,Y=k-i)}{\mathbb P(Z=k)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(X=i)\mathbb P(Y=k-i)}{\mathbb P(Z=k)}\\
\end{align}
Assuming there are no $j$ such that $\mathbb P(X=j)=1$ or $\mathbb P(Y=j)=1$ then
$$
\mathbb P(Z=k) = \begin{cases}
(1-p)(1-q),\ k=0\\
\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1}\mathbb P(Z=k-i)\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^i\left(\frac q{1-q}\right)^i,\ k\ne 0
\end{cases}
$$
Here $Z$ has Poisson binomial distribution. The computation would be quite tedious to do by hand.